# elasticsearch new typeless approach

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I just started working on elasticsearch and went through some tutorials that explained that an index in ES can be treated as a database and types can be treated as a collection/table and one can keep their database and collection like index and types.

After creating an ES instance and having a type deprecated error while creating types I got to know that elasticsearch in 7.x has deprecated creation of types and moved all documents under `_doc` type and 8.x will completely move into the typeless structure.

I am assuming that there should be another way to divide documents according to their collection within an index.

If there is no way please suggest the right way of maintaining collections/tables in EX 7.x and above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the reason as why types have been removed in [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed) and below is the excerpt from that very link.

> In an Elasticsearch index, fields that have the same name in different
> mapping types are backed by the same Lucene field internally. In other
> words, using the example above, the user_name field in the user type
> is stored in exactly the same field as the user_name field in the
> tweet type, and both user_name fields must have the same mapping
> (definition) in both types.
>
> This can lead to frustration when, for example, you want deleted to be
> a date field in one type and a boolean field in another type in the
> same index.
>
> On top of that, storing different entities that have few or no fields
> in common in the same index leads to sparse data and interferes with
> Lucene’s ability to compress documents efficiently.
>
> For these reasons, we have decided to remove the concept of mapping
> types from Elasticsearch.

***I am assuming that there should be another way to divide documents according to their collection within an index.***

Basically you have the below options:

- Have an altogether a [**separate index**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_index_per_document_type) for different document type
- Have [**a separate field**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_custom_type_field) *in the same index* which would help you differentiate two types of documents.

More information on that in [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_alternatives_to_mapping_types)

As for when you would want to make use of one over other, my bet is that if you find the fields in two different types, almost or mostly similar, then you can simply go for approach two. However if your *old index has two types with different fields altogether*, it would make sense to go for separate index.

Also your design of entire system comes into place, ingestion patterns, querying patterns(scoring, aggregations, transformations, index to index pipeline reindexing so other teams can use them for more insightful analytical info), what if one type is constantly getting lot of updates while other hardly any updates, best to keep them apart, right.

I believe the links I've shared has enough information.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This answer is really good. Adding more to it - I personally feel that adding a separate field within the same index seems to be more of less work effort compared to creating separate indices for multiple document types if indexed data is less.